# Doxygen doesn't document a class if \code is used

Tags: doxygen

This is either a bug in Doxygen or I am missing something. It is very easy to reproduce as follows:

I have the following class in a `foo.h` file:

```cpp
class Foo {

public:
    /**
     * This is a comment with \code value.
     */
    int bar(int value);

};
```

If I use Doxygen (version `1.8.17`) with the default configuration (generated by the `doxygen -g` command) then class `Foo` doesn't appear in the produced documentation. If I simply remove the `\code` symbol in the comment of `bar` then the class appears. If I put it back, it disappears again and so on.

This looks like a bug. Am I missing something ?

P.S.: I use MacOS `10.15.4` if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of the command `\code` is incorrect the closing `\endcode` is missing.
There are also warnings:

```
.../aa.h:10: warning: Reached end of file while still inside a (nested) comment. Nesting level 1 (probable line reference: 4)
...
.../aa.h:10: warning: File ended in the middle of a comment block! Perhaps a missing \endcode?
```

When correcting this you will get the message:

```
...aa.h:1: warning: Compound Foo is not documented.
```

but this is clear as the class itself is not documented.

Note it is a bit strange to have `\code` in a brief description, maybe you should also look at commands like `\a`, `\arg` and `\param`.

Comment: Thank you sir. I knew I was missing something :)